# Is there a Quicker way to Prove a $V$ is a Vector Space, Avoiding Axioms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm doing an exercise where I'm asked to, given a Vector space $V$ defined by complicated addition and scalar multiplication, show that it is closed under $\oplus$ and $\odot$ and to show that all axioms hold.

I was wondering, every time you're ask to prove whether it's a Vector Space, do you have to go through all axioms? Is there a shorter way to prove $V$ to be a Vector Space?

as suggested, the question I'm currently working on is:

Let $V$ = $R^2$, with $\oplus$ defined by:

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y  \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ $\oplus$  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} w \\ z \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ =  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x + w - 1\\ y + z + 4 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

and $\odot$ defined by:

$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y  \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x -  + 1\\ y + 4 - 4 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Show that $V$ is a vector space

Comment: Do you have to verify all the axioms? Yes, you do. However, if you know something about $V$, then there may be some shortcuts for doing this. If you add to your post by including a description of $V$, then that will make your question more specific, and you may get some good suggestions as to how to verify that $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: You can save a lot when there are fewer axioms. When I learned it, there was only a single axiom: "A vector space is an abelian group on which a field acts" :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It’s only fewer because you’ve hidden all of the Individual vector space axioms that need to be verified in a couple of other aggregate terms. Verifying that the structure is an abelian group still requires checking closure, existence of identity and inverses &c.

Comment: The fastest way to show that something complicated is a vector space is often to show that it is just a funny-looking copy of a vector space you already know, i.e. there is some bijection $\varphi \colon W \to V$ from a known vector space $W$, and you need to check that $\varphi(\alpha w) = \alpha \odot \varphi(w)$ and $\varphi(w + z) = \varphi(w) \oplus \varphi(z)$. In the case you have up there, it looks like $V$ is just a "shifted" copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$, as in we have set the "origin" to some other point than $(0, 0)$.

Comment: This is affine problem to solve.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen . The shortest def'n of a group (that I've seen) is a set G with a transitive binary operation (written as multiplication) such that for any x,y in G there exist unique z, z' with xz=z'x=y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our specific case, an easy way is to create a bijection from this given $V$ to the usual $\mathbb R^2$. In particular, consider the map $\varphi:\mathbb R^2\to V$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x+1,y-4)$. This is of course a bijection, but you can also verify that $$\begin{cases}\alpha\odot\varphi(x)=\varphi(\alpha x),\\\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)\oplus\varphi(y).\end{cases}$$
What this means is that the map $\varphi$ "carries over" the vector space structure of $\mathbb R^2$ onto $V$, so that $V$ is a vector space as well. In fact, we have even more: we've shown that there is an isomorphism of vector spaces between $V$ and $\mathbb R^2$.